# Evaluate the integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{|dz|}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Evaluate  the integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{|dz|}{z}$

**My idea:**

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$

then $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$

therefore $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{|dz|}{z}=\int ^{2\pi}_{0} e^{-i \theta}|d\theta|$

from here how to we processed

Comment: While I haven't come across the magnitude of a measure in my studies, your work seems plausible. The final integral appears to be zero, as can be seen by applying Euler's formula.

Comment: @Zahbaz Just asking, can we split into Real and Im parts and integrate separately?

Comment: @samjoe Again, I am unsure about what's going on with the measure $|dz|$ here, but to answer your question, yes, as far as I know, integration is linear wrt addition even with complex variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\theta$ varies from $o$ to $2\pi$,so $|d\theta | = d\theta$,so the problem is to find $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta} d\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta) d\theta = (0-0) + i.(1-1) = 0$.

Also integrating wrt $|dz|$ is a bit new scenario BTW can we do this?

Comment: $|dz|$ is the arc-length measure, and not a "new scenario" at all ...

Comment: I see, thanks! areas where they are frequently useful?...